# How to install dart packages offline?

Tags: dart

I am using dart and wanted to install dart packages for my projects.
I had tried

```
     pub get  
     pub install
```

but due to less connectivity its fails, so wanted to **install packages manually offline**.
how can i do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download your dependent dart package from dart pub.
http://pub.dartlang.org/packages

Search for the dependent packages and download appropriate version

**Be sure to download proper version which is required by the project.**

Answer (score 2):

You can copy/clone the source of the packages to a local directory and use path dependencies.

```yaml
dependencies:
  polymer:
    path: ../polymer
```

Answer (score 0):

Pub supports installing cached packages, just use the following command:

```
pub get --offline
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use windows, get in this link the wizard installation. Work for me.
https://gekorm.com/dart-windows/

Comment: i find other link better, https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive. This the DART SDK complety offline. Your weight is 197 megabyte.

Comment: the question about dart packages not dart sdk